# matlab: after project the surfed figure onto x-y view how to plot the region?

Tags: matlab, region, surf

I use surf(v,i,flag) to get the 3D plot. flag is choosing from -1 and 1.

Then I view the 3D figure in x-y view. I will see the projected region on x-y plane.

The region is blue or red depending on the flag value.

Does anyone know how to get a figure where the red region is grey and the blue region is white, and the figure is cleaned up without any line.

Answer (score 0):

you can use imagesc

imagesc(v)

colormap gray